# Accessing second table within a while loop

Tags: php, mysql, database

forgive me I just learned php this week, so I'm not sure I'm doing this all right.

It starts out accessing the DB, and the categories table for headers; it then takes that info and creates the header, pricing, and catalog links.

Then within that while loop after it completes the first part it's supposed to run a second while loop to access the products table to list all the products with the category_id that matches the cat_id from the categories table.

When it prints out it should be

> Header
>   Pricing PDF
>   Item Dimensions Image Image
>   Item Dimensions Image Image
>   Item Dimensions Image Image
>   etc
>
> Header
>   Pricing PDF
>   Item Dimensions Image Image
>   etc....

And so far the first while loop works but the second isn't.  Is there a correct way to pass the variable?  Can I just not access a second table while in a while loop for the first table?  I dunno...I've tried a few things, and nothing is working well

```
<?php
//connect to server
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','username','password');
//test connection
if (!$con)
{
    die ('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

//access primary DB 
mysql_select_db("main_db", $con);

//place table into variable
$categories = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories");


//begin table build
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($categories))
{
    //set shading variable
    $table_row = 0;

    //set current set   
    $cur_set = $row['cat_id'];
    //create document link and header
    echo "<a name='" . $row['cat_name'] . "'><h3>" . $row['cat_title'] . "</h3></a>";
    //create table and table formatting cell
    echo "<table id='productTable'><tr id='tableHead'>";
    //table width formattting here
    echo "<td style='width:165px;'></td>";
    echo "<td style='width:235px;'></td>";
    echo "<td style='width:155px;'>";
    //link and icons to category catalog
    echo "<a href='catalog/" . $row['cat_pdf'] . ".pdf'><img src='data/pdflogo.png' alt='pdf button' /></a>";
    //link and icons to category pricing sheet
    echo "<a href='catalog/" . $row['cat_pricing'] . ".pdf'><img src='data/pricinglogo.png' alt='pricing button' /></a>";
    //finish formatting
    echo "</td></tr>";

    //place table into variable
    $products = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id='" . $row['cat_id'] . "'");

    //begin table build
    while($table = mysql_fetch_array($products));
    {
        //create up row
        echo "<tr id='tr" . $table_row . "'>";
        //create first cell
        echo "<td>" . $table['prod_name'] . "</td>";
        //create second cell
        echo "<td>" . $table['prod_dim'] . "</td>";
        //create third cell
        echo "<td>";
        //create third cell, first image
        echo "<a href='catalog/" . $table['prod_img1'] . ".jpg'>" . "<img src='data/jpglogo.png' alt='image button' />" . "</a>";
        //create third cell, second image
        echo "<a href='catalog/" . $row2['prod_img2'] . ".jpg'>" . "<img src='data/jpglogo.png' alt='image button' />" . "</a>";
        //finish formatting
        echo "</td></tr>";
        //cycle row
        if ($table_row == 0)
            {
                    $table_row = 1;
            }
        else
            {
                $table_row = 0;
            }

    //end table
    echo "</table>";
    }
}

//close connection
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Take a look at JOIN queries in SQL. You could achieve the same in only one loop.

Comment: He could do what @Romain and Rolando are saying, but first since he is new to php he should do it step by step to learn, right?

Comment: New to php and mysql; been learning on w3schools.  I didn't even hear about this PDO/MySQLi stuff until I came here and started looking for other people with a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be more streamlined to perform an INNER JOIN on both tables

```
SELECT
    A.cat_id,A.cat_name,A.cat_title,A.cat_pdf,A.cat_pricing,
    B.prod_name,B.prod_img1,B.prod_img2
FROM categories A INNER JOIN products B ON A.cat_id = B.category_id;
```

You can iterate on A.cat_id

This is my proposed suggestion (braces might be off, but here is what the iteration on cat_id should look like). Please change the style for starting and stopping tags.

```
<?php
//connect to server
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','username','password');
//test connection
if (!$con)
{
    die ('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

//access primary DB 
mysql_select_db("main_db", $con);

//place table into variable
$categories = mysql_query("SELECT A.cat_id,A.cat_name,A.cat_title,A.cat_pdf,A.cat_pricing,B.prod_name,B.prod_img1,B.prod_img2 FROM categories A INNER JOIN products B ON A.cat_id = B.category_id");

$current_catid = -1;

//begin table build
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($categories))
{
        if ( $current_catid != $row['cat_id'] )
        {
            if ( $current_catid > -1 ) { echo "</table>"; }
            $current_catid != $row['cat_id']

    //set shading variable
    $table_row = 0;

    //set current set   
    $cur_set = $row['cat_id'];
    //create document link and header
    echo "<a name='" . $row['cat_name'] . "'><h3>" . $row['cat_title'] . "</h3></a>";
    //create table and table formatting cell
    echo "<table id='productTable'><tr id='tableHead'>";
    //table width formattting here
    echo "<td style='width:165px;'></td>";
    echo "<td style='width:235px;'></td>";
    echo "<td style='width:155px;'>";
    //link and icons to category catalog
    echo "<a href='catalog/" . $row['cat_pdf'] . ".pdf'><img src='data/pdflogo.png' alt='pdf button' /></a>";
    //link and icons to category pricing sheet
    echo "<a href='catalog/" . $row['cat_pricing'] . ".pdf'><img src='data/pricinglogo.png' alt='pricing button' /></a>";
    //finish formatting
    echo "</td></tr>";
        }

//create up row
    echo "<tr id='tr" . $table_row . "'>";
    //create first cell
    echo "<td>" . $table['prod_name'] . "</td>";
    //create second cell
    echo "<td>" . $table['prod_dim'] . "</td>";
    //create third cell
    echo "<td>";
    //create third cell, first image
    echo "<a href='catalog/" . $table['prod_img1'] . ".jpg'>" . "<img src='data/jpglogo.png' alt='image button' />" . "</a>";
    //create third cell, second image
    echo "<a href='catalog/" . $row2['prod_img2'] . ".jpg'>" . "<img src='data/jpglogo.png' alt='image button' />" . "</a>";

    //finish formatting
    echo "</td></tr>";
        //cycle row
    if ($table_row == 0)
    {
        $table_row = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $table_row = 0;
    }

    //end table (Fix this, might produce extra table tag)
    echo "</table>";
}

//close connection
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You'll have to forgive me, I'm a very visual person and I'm just not seeing how this inner join works.  Is it basically like creating an array inside of an array?  Also, as far as the way you reorganized it, you made it so that it constantly runs the while loop, and the if statement creates the category header on the first pass only correct?

Comment: It's 1 query to put together categories and products. Take the worst case, 12 categories and 20 products. The query will generate 240 rows. You only had to connect to mysql one time. With your original code, you would connect 13 times (once to categories and 12 times to products). More efficicent retrieval. Run the query by hand and see the output.

Comment: The JOIN would literally be like a 2D representation of an array within an array. Example: Table1 has (a,b,c) and Table2 has (1,2,3,4). An INNER JOIN produces (a,1),(a,2),(a,3),(a,4),(b,1),(b,2),(b,3),(b,4),(c,1),(c,2),(c,3),(c,4).

Comment: That's hurting my head, but I'll look into it; thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading relative data, so a short answer is no, because of the overhead you will probably have if you would select them with joins.

Also, try to limit the overhead created by the * by selecting only what you want and not everything.

Also follow Truth's recommendations, for new mysql(i) calls. Once you get a hang with sql and php, you can move to other types of database calls (using object oriented code -- or activerecord), but please try to understand how mysql calls are being done first.